# Запуск видео при скроллинге

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

Подскажите, как запустить youtube видео при условии того что пользователь отскролил 1585px

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/любое видео?controls=1&autoplay=0&cc_load_policy=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=1&showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

$(window).scroll(function () {

        win = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(win < 1585){

            $("#ytplayer").trigger("click");

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обновить URL видео, добавив параметр `&autoplay=1`

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {

        win = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(win < 1585){

          $("#ytplayer")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";

        }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/любое видео?controls=1&autoplay=0&cc_load_policy=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=1&showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: так не работает, постоянно "дрыбает" экран, видео не запускается

Comment: @ChromeChrome экран дрыбает, скорей всего потому, что при скроле постоянно видео перезагружается. нужно добавить условие, что если параметр `autoplay=1` уже присутствует в URL, то, чтобы видео не обновлялось.

Comment: @ChromeChrome должно работать, вот ещё похожий (рабочий) пример для наглядности: https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/dyLAC

Comment: спасибо, буду пробывать